# Broken ValueQ function in Mma12.2?

Tags: core-language, expression-test, compatibility, upvalues

```
f[x] ^= 1;
ValueQ[g[x]]
```

returns `True` in Mathematica 12.2. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The behavior of `ValueQ` has changed in version 12.2. In fact, you can provide a `Method -> "Legacy"` option to match the behavior the function had in Version 12.1 and earlier:

[image: reproducing old behavior]

The Details portion of the [documentation for `ValueQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html) now states that the default method in the 12.2 implementation (`Automatic`) effectively uses `"OwnValuesPresent"` if `expr` is a symbol and `"SymbolDefinitionsPresent"` otherwise (which means that "one or more symbols have any sort of definition present"). As I understand it, `g[x]` is not a symbol, so the latter is used.

This change for version 12.2 is also mentioned in the [list of incompatible changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#1811902644) between MMA versions.

Comment: This is also mentioned in the [list of incompatible changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html).

Comment: @J.M. Good pointer! I added the link. I had not come across that list yet: very instructive read.

Comment: So, the up  value of x counts by default. Still, I can not think of any use case of such a behavior and would consider this as a bug.

Comment: I noticed this when working through L. Shrifkin's programming text (section 2.2.7).  Can anyone explain the motivation for the change, which to me makes more sense than the pre 12.2 behavior?